# Presto custom PasswordAuthenticator plugin for coordinator authentication is not triggered

Tags: bigdata, presto

I created a presto custom password authenticator plugin (internal) by making a copy of the LDAP plugin and modifying it.  You can see that code here: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/tree/master/presto-password-authenticators/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/password.

I created copies of the Authenticator, AuthenticatorFactory, and the config, and modified them to basically just take a user/password from the config and to only allow that user in.  I also put the new class in the PasswordAuthenticatorPlugin registration code.

I can see the plugin loading when presto is started, but it doesn't appear to do anything despite no errors being present.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I had already found a solution to this, I'm just recording it on SO as I originally came here and found no help.

To make a custom password plugin work, you actually need HTTPS enabled for communication with the coordinator.  You can actually see this recommendation at the bottom of their documentation:

https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/develop/password-authenticator.html

> Additionally, the coordinator must be configured to use password authentication and have HTTPS enabled.

So, the steps to make it work are:

1. Make sure your main config.properties has "http-server.authentication.type=PASSWORD".
2. Make sure you add a password-authenticator.properties next to config properties with content like the sample in the link above.  But make sure you use your string from your authenticator as the name, and that you add your configuration properties instead (user name and password).
3. Set up a JKS store or a real certificate (some instructions here from Presto for JKS: https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/security/tls.html).
4. Add SSL config to your config.properties.

   - http-server.https.enabled=true
   - http-server.https.port=8443
   - http-server.https.keystore.path=/etc/presto-keystore/keystore.jks
   - http-server.https.keystore.key=password123
5. Set up your JDBC driver to use the same key store.

I wrote up a blog on it with a bit more detail as well if any of that doesn't make sense.  But after doing all this, you should find that it does require a password and it does enforce your plugin.

https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2019/06/18/presto-custom-password-authentication-plugin-internal/

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the post. Did you ever get around to making an external plugin for this?

Comment: Sorry, we maintain a fork in my company, so I just copied the other internal one and modified it to my needs.  The only external plugin I ever attempted was a custom hive plugin and it did not seem to work out... odd dependency issues kept coming up in the project structure (I'm not sure it can work with the hive plugin; I did spend quite a bit of time and asked around on forums).  So, I had to do an internal one there in the end (which is how we started a fork).